# Undefined Response For Ajax Request With Validation Errors Form

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

**the response is Undefined for the form validation errors**

controller method handle the request and store or send back validation errors to client side with json response

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator =  $this->validate(request(), [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' =>  'required'
          ]);

          if($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => $validator->errors()->toArray()]);
          } else {
            $report = new Report;
            $report->name = 'username';
            $report->phone = '012345679';
            $report->title = $request->title;
            $report->body =  $request->body;
            $result = $report->save();
            return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'your report has been sent successfuly']);
          }
    }
```

here if the button clicked and there no radio button checked or the body is not filled with a message body, laravel validation errors must displays to user but it gives me Undefined message

```
jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {

    $('#sendrepo').click(function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                var selected = $('input[type="radio"]:checked');

                var title = selected.val();
                var body = $('textarea#repobdy').val();
                var url = 'api/report';

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: { title: title, body: body  },
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#repo-fel').remove();
                            $('.tg-formtheme h3').remove();
                            $('.repo-message').append('<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>'+ data.message +'</strong></div>');
                        },
                        error: function( data){
                            $('.repo-message').append('<ul><li>'+ data.errors +'</li></ul>');
                        }

                });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: { title: title, body: body  },
            success: function(data){
                if (data.success) {
                    $('#repo-fel').remove();
                    $('.tg-formtheme h3').remove();
                    $('.repo-message').append('<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>'+ data.message +'</strong></div>');
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                var errors = data.responseJSON;
                $.each(errors, function(i, v){
                    $('.repo-message').append('<ul><li>'+ v +'</li></ul>');
                });
            }

        });
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I had removed the success true/false and the same result it returns Undefined message

Comment: i had do it the same , there is no  validation errors shows only undefined message , all i need to show laravel validation errors to user

Comment: Is it undefined when you generate the errors? Because I have tried this code and it works well, when the validation fails.

Comment: Good to hear.

I have edited my answer as the right solution.

Comment: i already answer it below and i will edit it with full explanation thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

directly without $validator->fails() , the errors will response automatically

```
public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $validator =  $this->validate(request(), [
                'title' => 'required',
                'body' =>  'required'
              ]);

                $report = new Report;
                $report->name = 'username';
                $report->phone = '012345679';
                $report->title = $request->title;
                $report->body =  $request->body;
                $result = $report->save();
                return response()->json(['message' => 'your report has been sent successfuly']);
              }
        }
```

the answer is have to responseJSON for the data and iterate through it

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: { title: title, body: body  },
            success: function(data){
                if (data.success) {
                    $('#repo-fel').remove();
                    $('.tg-formtheme h3').remove();
                    $('.repo-message').append('<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>'+ data.message +'</strong></div>');
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                var errors = data.responseJSON;
                $.each(errors.errors, function(i, v){
                    $('.repo-message').append('<ul><li>'+ v +'</li></ul>');
                });
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now so if i'm not right just ignore my answer, but on validator i never user request as a function, you can try something like this and see if it returns the correct errors:

```
$validator =  $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' =>  'required'
      ]);
```

Comment: you can check laracast.com for validation